# CreateFile() "D:/nginx-1.9.12/nginx-1.9.12/html/war/helloworld/greet" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: gwt, nginx, file-permissions

I am a newbie to nginx. I am trying to implement a basic hello-world program for remote logging in GWT. I am able to successfully log using Tomcat. 
Similarly, I am trying to run a RPC (again Hello World) program on the two servers, works perfectly fine in tomcat however fails in nginx.
Following is my nginx.conf:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log  error;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


    http {
            include       mime.types;
            default_type  application/octet-stream;

            sendfile        on;
            tcp_nopush     on;

            #keepalive_timeout  0;
            keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  localhost;

                #charset koi8-r;

                location / {
                root   D:/nginx-1.9.12/nginx-1.9.12/html;
                index  index.html index.htm;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #   listen       443 ssl;
    #   server_name  localhost;
    #   ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #   ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;
    #
    #   ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    #
    #   location / {
    #   root   html;
    #   index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

This is the log from error_logs:

```
2016/03/15 11:42:55 [warn] 5676#2408: "user" is not supported, ignored in D:\nginx-1.9.12\nginx-1.9.12/conf/nginx.conf:1

2016/03/15 11:43:08 [error] 5676#896: *1 CreateFile() "D:/nginx-1.9.12/nginx-1.9.12/html/war/helloworld/greet" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /war/helloworld/greet HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/war/HelloWorld.html"
```

After a lot of searching around, I am of the opinion that this is a permission issue. My user does not have a write permission. But I am unable to solve this problem.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: facing the same issue here

Comment: As for me simple removing of "ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;" solved the problem. But I have no idea why.